# Rails simple-form datepicker how to add data-behaviour

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui

I have a Rails app using jquery-ui datePicker.

Inside of a simple_form I have two fields. The first one is just a test field. The first one has datePicker working.  I'm trying to get "data-behaviour" into the simple_form f.input line.  But, I've got the wrong syntax.

```
<input type="text" data-behaviour='datepicker' >
<%= f.input :exp_date, :data-behaviour => 'datepicker', :as => :string, :label => 'Date', :input_html => {:value => Date.today.to_s} %>
```

This is my jquery:

```
$(document).on "focus", "[data-behaviour~='datepicker']", (e) ->
  $(this).datepicker
    format: "yyyy-mm-dd"
    weekStart: 1
    autoclose: true
```

How can I get the data-behavior='datepicker' into the f.input line?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like

```
#old hash syntax
:data => { :behavior => "datepicker" }
#new syntax
data: { behavior: "datepicker" }
```

Comment: It worked when I put it into the :input_html section.  Thanks!